# generate new row in pandas if column value is over certain value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm writing a function to get the `HOR_df` output below by feeding in 2 dataframes, `planned_routes` and `actual_shippers`.

The function should look at the actual_pallets (from `actual_shippers` df) and then look at `planned_routes` to see if the columns actual pallets > max_truck_capacity. If it does, it should generate a new row, like in the picture below.

Visualisation of the inputs and wanted output:
[image: dfs]

### Note

In the above case: S1 had planned 10 pallets, but with the new actual_pallets was increased so that the max_truck_capacity is too small to handle the new actual_pallets. Therefore a new row is generated with the S2 ID, and the 3 needed extra pallets.

HOR_df has in this case made sure that on the 1st of December 2021, the actual_pallets for shipper S2 were split up onto routes of 10 and 3 pallets separately, instead of the 10 pallets that were in the initial `planned_routes`.

#### Potential idea how it should be done

I'm not sure what's the most efficient way to do this, for instance if I should build something that iteratively goes through and "fill the routes up" with the new "actual_pallet" data?

```
# x = planned_routes
# y = actual_shippers
# z = cost of adhocs and cancellations
# w = truck eligibility

def optimal_trips(x, y, z, w): 
    # Step 1: Take in actual shippers package and pallet data 
    
    # Step 2: Take the actual data and feed it into the planned routes and add routes based on demand.
        
    # Step 3: return a df with the new optimal routes.
```

#### Code for the dfs (to replicate)

**Input 1:**

```
planned_routes = pd.DataFrame({
                    'date':['2021-12-01','2021-12-02'],
                    'planned_route_id':['R1', 'R2'],                    
                    'S1_id':['S1', 'S1'],                    
                    'S2_id':['S2', 'S2'],                    
                    'S3_id':['NaN', 'NaN'],                    
                    'S4_id':['NaN', 'NaN'],
                    'S1_planned_packages':[110, 100],                    
                    'S2_planned_packages':[120, 100],                    
                    'S3_planned_packages':['NaN', 'NaN'],                    
                    'S4_planned_packages':['NaN', 'NaN'],
                    'total_planned_packages':[230, 200],
                    'S1_planned_pallets':[11, 10],                    
                    'S2_planned_pallets':[12, 10],                    
                    'S3_planned_pallets':['NaN', 'NaN'],                    
                    'S4_planned_pallets':['NaN', 'NaN'],                   
                    'total_pallets':[23, 20],
                    'truck_max_capacity':[24, 24],
                    'cost_route':[120, 120]
                     })
```

**Input 2:**

```
actual_shippers = pd.DataFrame({
                    'date':['2021-12-01','2021-12-01','2021-12-02','2021-12-02'],
                    'shipper_id':['S1', 'S2','S1', 'S2'],
                    'actual_packages':[140, 130, 140, 130],
                    'shipper_spp':[10, 10, 10, 10],
                    'actual_pallets':[14, 13, 14, 13],
                    'shipper_max_eligibility':[24, 24, 24, 24],
                    'truck_max_capacity':[24, 24, 24, 24]
                     })
```

**Wanted output:**

```
HOR_df = pd.DataFrame({
                    'date':['2021-12-01','2021-12-01', '2021-12-02', '2021-12-02'],
                    'planned_route_id':['R1', 'R3','R2', 'R4'],                    
                    'S1_id':['S1', 'S2', 'S1', 'S2'],                    
                    'S2_id':['S2', 'NaN', 'S2', 'NaN'],                    
                    'S3_id':['NaN', 'NaN','NaN', 'NaN'],                    
                    'S4_id':['NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN'],
                    'S1_actual_packages':[140, 0, 140, 0],                    
                    'S2_actual_packages':[100, 30, 100, 30],                    
                    'S3_actual_packages':['NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN'],                    
                    'S4_actual_packages':['NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN'],
                    'total_planned_packages':[240, 30, 240, 30], # sum(S1_actual_packages, S2_actual packages, S3... etc)
                    'S1_actual_pallets':[14, 3, 14, 3],                    
                    'S2_actual_pallets':[10, 'NaN', 10, 'NaN'],                    
                    'S3_actual_pallets':['NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN'],                    
                    'S4_actual_pallets':['NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN'],                   
                    'total_pallets':[24, 3, 24, 3], #sum(S1_actual_pallets, S2 ... etc)
                    'truck_max_capacity':[24, 24, 24, 24], 
                    'cost_route':[120, 130, 120, 130]
                     })
```